# Joomla v3.0 Javascript jQuery Issue - has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

Using a slider module on Joomla v3.0

I have tried several module extensions & all come back with the same error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'favslider'**

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('.favslider').favslider({
        //error here ---> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'favslider'
        animation: "slide",
        directionNav: true,
        keyboardNav: true,
        mousewheel: false,
        slideshow: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        randomize: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,

        controlNav: true,
        start: function (slider) {
            jQuery('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
});
```

Url to site (shortened, as running on temp ip url & not allowed to post ip here)
http://goo.gl/ipCJn

Any idea's - lost as to what can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means `$.fn.favslider` is not a function, ie you don't have this jquery plugin loaded. 
So you may start with checking if you have this joomla extension and its jquery plug.

**Edit**

If you have added this extension, then check `$.fn.favslider` in the console on your page and see if it is defined.

If it is, it means that the code you show us is called before the extensions are loaded. To confirm this you can use a `setTimeout` to defer your code execution and see if it is really an issue of loading order.

If it is, then if you control the scripts that are inserted in your page, please order them correctly.